# Building Angular project ((node:20072) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated)

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

I am trying to build a new Angular project, but every time I am having the same problem.
Moreover, I'm using Angular 10 and the latest version of Node.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKzfj.png)